# ROS Answers SE migration: urdf error

Tags: gazebo, rviz, urdf, ubuntu, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I am trying to build my own robot according to this link:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Create%20your%20own%20urdf%20file

It appears to me some errors:

seec@ubuntu:~$ rosmake urdfdom_model
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['urdfdom_model']                           
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/seec/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130722-140052
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['urdfdom_model'] to:
[]                              
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['urdfdom_model']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
seec@ubuntu:~$  rosrun urdfdom_model check_urdf my_robot.urdf
[rospack] Error: stack/package urdfdom_model not found

Is there some special place to save in it "my_robot.urdf" this .urdf file?
I do not know what is the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68032/urdf-error/) by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both `rosmake` and `rosrun` told you the same error.  You don't have the package *urdfdom_model*.  I believe some of the confusion has to do with the renaming of some of the urdf packages from Fuerte to Groovy.  I'm presuming you are using Fuerte, so try this command instead:

```
rosrun urdf_parser check_urdf my_urdf.xml
```

See also [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/57639/urdfdom_model-problem/).

**EDIT**
I just updated the wiki page you linked to try and make this a bit more clear.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2013-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1